# Evenly Distribute Names to Rows based on Countif

Tags: vba, excel, counter, lookup-tables

I am having trouble writing a bit of VBA code and am looking for suggestions on how to complete.

My data set will contain a column of Categories which could be A, B, or C. The number of rows will always vary. Once I set the Categories to an array I want loop through and lookup the value against a table on another tab but if the category is C, I need to count the number of rows containing C then evenly distribute those rows to a list of employee names within the table. The lookup for category A & B is now working. Have been able to count rows with category C on both data set & table. Unsure how to correctly insert employee names into rows up to "CntPerStaff" number then move onto next employee name in table.

```
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim Arr1 As Variant, Arr2 As Variant

'Finds last row in data set
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Set data columns to arrays
    Arr1 = Range("AP2:AP" & LastRow).Value   'Category
    Arr2 = Range("AQ2:AQ" & LastRow).Value   'Employee

    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr1)

    If Arr1(i, 1) = "A" Then
        Arr2(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("A", Worksheets("Tables").Range("CATEGORYID"), 2, False) 
    ElseIf Arr1(i, 1) = "B" Then
        Arr2(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("B", Worksheets("Tables").Range("CATEGORYID"), 2, False)
    Else 'Need to insert countif functionality
    End If
Next i

'Place employee name array into spreadsheet
    Range("AQ2").Resize(UBound(Arr2, 1), 1).Value = Arr2
```

This is what I have so far on the countif code:

```
Dim Count As Variant, CntPerStaff As Variant, Arr1 As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, Cnt As Long, Staff As Long, CntStart As Long

 'Finds last row in data set
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Cnt = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AP2:AP" & LastRow), "C")
    Staff = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Tables").Range("CATEGORYID"), "C")
    CntPerStaff = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Cnt / Staff, 0)
```

[Example of Table and Data (red is info which macro will output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CApn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly the effect I was going for but it does work to give an even distribution of rows to the employees listed in the table.  I used the code for determining A & B as written above, then sorted that column to get the blank rows on the bottom of the data before running this loop.

```
'Set table and copy names
Set Source = Worksheets("Tables").ListObjects("CATEGORYID")    
    With Source
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="C"
        SourceDataRows = .ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With

'Loop to paste names
    Do While x < LastRow
        x = Cells(Rows.Count, "AQ").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            With Worksheets("Data").Range("AQ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Loop

 'Remove any names which pasted past the last row of data
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A" & LastRow + 1 & ":AQ" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
    End With
```